# JS onclick div disappears until an animation is played

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have an `object1` and `object2`.

`object1` has an animation with `delay: 0s`

`object2` has an animation with `delay: 0.5s`

When you click on **1.**, both objects properly assign `.animation`,but `object2` after 0.5s, whitch is what I want, everything goes fine.

But here is the problem, when you click on **2.**, objects assign `.animation-back`, `object1` does his thing properly, BUT`object2` disappears for that 0.5s and after that he does an animation.

I probably know, that this is because also removing class `.animation`, and it's waiting for "play" `.animation-back`, but when I delete `.removeClass('animation-back')`, etc..., it will jump into some kind of loop or how can I call it, you can try it yourself.

```js
$(".text1").click(function(){
  $(".object1").addClass('animation').removeClass('animation-back');
  $(".object2").addClass('animation').removeClass('animation-back');
});
$(".text2").click(function(){
  $(".object1").addClass('animation-back').removeClass('animation');
  $(".object2").addClass('animation-back').removeClass('animation');
});
```

```css
a{
  font-size:150%;
}
.text1{
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-left:42px;
  font-size:150%;
}
.text2{
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-left:42px;
  font-size:150%;
}
.object1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin:2em;
  margin-left: 150px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}
.object1.animation{
  animation: animation1 0.7s ease-in-out 0s 1 forwards;
}
.object1.animation-back{
  animation: animation2 0.7s ease-in-out 0s 1 forwards;
}
.object2{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin:2em;
  margin-left: 150px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}
.object2.animation{
  animation: animation1 0.7s ease-in-out 0.5s 1 forwards;
}
.object2.animation-back{
  animation: animation2 0.7s ease-in-out 0.5s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes animation1 {
  from { margin-left: 150px; opacity: 0; }
  to { margin-left: 0px; opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes animation2 {
  from { margin-left: 0px; opacity: 1; }
  to { margin-left: 150px; opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text1"><a>1.</a></div>
<div class="text2"><a>2.</a></div>
<div class="object1"></div>
<div class="object2"></div>
```

Thanks for advices, have a nice day!

Comment: Please show the relevant code directly in your question.

Comment: Not certain what expected result is ?

Comment: @guest271314 The expected result is that the second box doesn't disappear before animating to the right.

Comment: @MikeC, yes, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is your default class is making the box opacity 0 and your animation is delaying .5s so its taking half a second before the opacity is back to 1. just update the object 2 class to include the default state of the object

```
.object2.animation-back {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 0px;
    animation: animation2 0.7s ease-in-out 0.5s 1 forwards;
}
```

Comment: Here you go, my savior, thanks a lot! Have a nice day ! :)

Answer (score 3):

You set the `animation-fill-mode` to `forwards`, which will only maintain the *final* animation state (after completion). If you want to display the *initial* state as soon as it is applied to an element, set `animation-fill-mode` to `backwards` (or `both` for both `forwards` and `backwards`.

```
.object2.animation-back {
    animation: animation2 0.7s ease-in-out 0.5s 1 both;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

---

As a side note, you may find it worthwhile to use just *one* set of keyframes, and setting `animation-direction` to `reverse` to reverse the animation.

```
.object2.animation {
    animation: animation1 0.7s ease-in-out 0.5s 1 both;
}
.object2.animation-back {
    animation: animation1 0.7s ease-in-out 0.5s 1 reverse both;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction